# Primeng p-calendar same size as parent

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using p-calendar from the primeng within a tabletree. How can I make the p-calendar field same size as the cell it sits in? Or mor general - how can I make it same size as a parent div?

You can make it work with absolute width using style and inputStyle - but my table is resizable - so it doesnt work in this case. I tried as recommended at various places:

```
<p-calendar appendTo="body"  [style]="{'width':'95%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'95%'}"
</p-calendar>
```

But this doesnt work since the button of the date selector has a fixed size.

This appears to me to be a very basic requirement - being able to make a component same size as its parent. Really surprised this doesnt work.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 24):

This works for me:

```
<p-calendar [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}" [timeOnly]="true"></p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried below to achieve this:

Add your own class to override the CSS of date container. As I added class="treetableDate"

```
    <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date1" 
[style]="{'width':'70%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'70%'}" class="treetableDate"></p-calendar>
```

Now override the CSS of calendar component. Like below:

```
.treetableDate .ui-widget-content{
    width: 80%; // or in pixel depends how much width you want.
}
```

**Note: Do not override .ui-widget-content directly. Otherwise it will affect the width of each and every component in your application. Using your own class it will affect only that particular element.**

Comment: Hi, tried - but doesnt work. The p-calendar field wont be the size of the parent div/ table cell. I also played around with the percentages. I guess the issue is the calendar icon has a fixed size but the input field has a variable size. It would work if I can set the width of the input field to 100%-width of icon. But I havent found a way to do this.

I also have some problem understanding how style and inputStyle are applied to this component. If set style="width: 100%" I would expect this sizes the whole calendar component incl. icon. But this is obviously not the case.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet to look into it properly. Even I found it weird that we have to use both [style] and [inputStyle] in terms of applying CSS. Individually they are not working.

Comment: Hi, I already found a solution: style="''width':'100%,[display': 'flex', 'flex-direction': 'row-reverse}'' is doing the job!

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem where I was seeing the calendar popup inherit the width of the column it was in (I was using it for a column filter on a p-table), given my column was fairly narrow the calendar was narrow also, so if I widened the calendar using

```
[style]="{'width':'300px'}"
```

then my column widened also which wasn't what I wanted.

To keep my column width ***and*** have the popup appear in full/normal size I added this to the p-table element:
`#myTable`
and in the p-calendar element I added this:
`[appendTo]="myTable"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the appendTo="body", it's change the context of monthpicker.
To fix, I used a div in appendTo.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case anyone comes across this issue in future and finds none of the above solutions affective.  Please see below.

OP mentioned parent div:

```html
<div>
  <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date1" class="treetableDate"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

```css
:host {
  ...
  > div {
    display: flex;
    > p-calendar {
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is work for me

```
::ng-deep .ui-calendar {
  width: 100%;
}

::ng-deep .ui-calendar .ui-inputtext {
  width: calc(100% - 2.357em);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).